# Can we put triples in specific graph or collections for Triples generated via TDE?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10, tde

I know that TDE generates unmanaged triples, and unmanaged triples are not part of graphs by default. So is there any way to put these TDE generated triples in specific graphs or collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a named graph. Unmanaged triples will inherit the collection of the document.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/tde#id_67662

> An extracted triples graph cannot be specified through the template. The graph is implicitly defined by the document's collection similar to embedded triples.

https://www.marklogic.com/blog/managed-vs-unmanaged-triples/

> Document collections are what’s important here. MarkLogic collections are used to represent the notion of graphs in SPARQL. Graphs are useful in addressing subsets of triples. For instance, you could use graphs to distinguish triples from different sources, or triples about different topics, or triples with different quality measures. These are just a few of the many ways in which you could use graphs. Document collections have the very same purpose, but for documents. Since all triples are persisted in documents in the database, using document collections for graphs makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! But do we have any way to check the TDE triples collections ?